# Shapiro–Wilk normality test

Tags: r, normality-assumption, shapiro-wilk-test

I'm trying to check for normality using Shapiro–Wilk normality test.
I have a two-way ANOVA (2x3) and would like to run this test on each of the 6 groups.
Which function should I use to be able to run it per group?
Can I use: `shapiro.test` or maybe `tapply(y, x, shapiro.test)`?

Comment: The advice on here tends to be that such normality testing is essentially useless. This is worth reading: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless.

Comment: If you're going to check for normality (by formal test or by looking plots) you should look at 'residuals' from the model not look at data for each factor separately. // The link seems to deal mainly with problems checking for normality in very large samples.

Comment: There is a statistical question here, so I'm voting to keep this thread open.  You need a *diagnostic* rather than a formal test.  Consider a graphical diagnostic, such as a collection of probability plots of the group residuals.